# Zero MQ publisher subscriber (pub/sub)

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish, publish-subscribe

I have implemented a simple pub/sub example. I am sending a simple hello message and trying to receive it at the subscriber.
My publisher code is -

```
std::string msg = "hello,";
zmq::message_t message(static_cast<const void*> (msg.data()), msg.size());
publisher.send(message);
```

My subscriber code -

```
zmq::message_t msgReceive;
subscriber.recv(&msgReceive);   
const char* buffer_body = static_cast<const char*>(msgReceive.data());
printf("Message: %s\n",buffer_body);
```

The output i am getting is - "hello,Socket-Type" 
instead of "hello,"

I am unable to figure out where is the mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
const char* buffer_body = static_cast<const char*>(msgReceive.data());
```

to

```
const char* buffer_body = static_cast<const char*>(msgReceive.data(), msgReceive.size());
```

That way you can tell the C_String where to terminate based on the length of the message rather than letting it terminate on its own when it finds the first null character.

For more information see [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc11).